# Оптимальные размеры сайта

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Я хочу сделать оптимизацию сайта под несколько определенных разрешений( width = 1366 \ 1920 \ 1280 \ 960 ).

И хочу, чтобы минимальная ширина сайта при открытии была 960, даже если сайт открыт на экране с меньшей, чем 960, шириной. (Делаю через `@media screen`)

Хочу узнать:

1. Если я напишу `<meta name="viewport" content="min-width=960, initial-scale=1">` в голове ДОМ, то будет ли реализована моя задумка по минимальному разрешению?
2. Есть ли более продуктивные способы помимо `@media screen` реализовать оптимизацию под разрешения?

Буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: Нашел ответ только что, к сожалению только на 1 свой вопрос. <meta name="viewport" content="width=960, initial-scale=1"> - и то, чего я хотел получено.